# double integration using both orders of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Compute the following double integral twice showing both possible orders for the integration. $$\iint_R xy^2+4x \,\mathrm dA$$ where $R$ is the region enclosed by the graphs $x=\sqrt y$, $y=4$ and $x=0$.

I got this question wrong on a test -- I didn't know how to do it so I left it blank -- and my teacher said to graph the footprint but I don't know what that means.

edit: I know what graphing a footprint means. I'm still unclear on the integration.

Answer (score 0):

In one order you integrate w.r.t. $x$ from $0$ to $\sqrt y$ and then w.r.t. $y$ from $0$ to $4$. In the other order you integrate w.r.t. $y$ from $x^{2}$ to $4$ and then w.r.t. $x$ from $0$ to $2$.

Comment: so I did the question that way but got two different answers. `\frac {112/3}` and 8

Comment: I don't know what mistakes you are making but the answer is $48$. I used both the orders of integration and got this answer in each case. Unless you show your entire calculation I cannot help you. @ufotink